# Communicating With Two Machines With ROS2

Tags: ros, arduino#ros#raspberry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to start up communication between two machines running ROS2 Galactic using the examples:

```
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
```

and

```
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener
```

- Both machines are on the same
  network,
- Both machines have
  multicasting enabled
- Both machines
  can ping each other
- Both machines
  have the same netmask
- I have also
  tried running the examples on
  different networks with no success
- Both machines have "export
  ROS_DOMAIN_ID=30" in their .bashrc

When running the two example nodes on the same machine everything works fine.

Please tell if you need any more info.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398307/communicating-with-two-machines-with-ros2/) by [Jacob G.](https://answers.ros.org/users/90657/jacob-g./) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2022-03-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks a lot for the answer! I tried out the different RMWs but nothing seemed to work. Those things didn't fix it for me.

Instead the problem was solved by: 1. Switching to a different network. (I was on a network with extra security layers that might have messed with the communication). 2. The firewall on my two machines were blocking the communication. - As a quick fix you can disable firewall by using the following command:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

You can check the status of your firewall do typing:

```
sudo ufw status
```

It is not recommended to have your firewall disabled at all times however, so only use this as a way to test if it is the firewall that is the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Jacob G.](https://answers.ros.org/users/90657/jacob-g./) with karma: 41 on 2022-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sam_Prt](https://answers.ros.org/users/108956/sam_prt/) on 2022-10-11**:
Hello,
Is there a way to keep the firewall on and to configure the network to allow the topics to pass ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which RMW implementation do you use?

I got better results with [Fast RTPS](https://github.com/ros2/rmw_fastrtps) on 2 AWS instances for connecting nodes and their topics. There is more documentation about its configuration too.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-03-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1